# How to get text value of elements in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium

It's the first time I ever use Selenium. I'm trying to get the text value of these two elements:
[element1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clQJC.png)

[element 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFeRR.png)

I was getting the first element just fine, through the h3 tag. Now, both elements are not appearing. I can't locate through anything that uses ID as it changes quite a lot.

Any help?

Update @Chikabala : This it the output when the .text is in the print statement.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\re123el\Py5123s\create\try.py", line 42, in <module>
    print(elementList.text)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'
```

This is the output when  the .text is added to the end of the xpath:

```
vscGnRMlqsD8rQ
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rebel\PycharmProjects\create\try.py", line 40, in <module>
    elementList = sheto.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'
```

Update #2:
This is the original code:

```
keto = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("h3")[1].text
print(keto)
sheto = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@class='preftable']/tbody/tr/td[@class='prefright']").text
print(sheto)
```

This is the original output:

```
C:\Users\rebel\PycharmProjects\create\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/rebel/PycharmProjects/create/try.py
GWrS4IyFkO-bfw


Process finished with exit code 0
```

Domain is: https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps
Status: Signed in, app created, script
Elements wanted: app id (h3 tag) and secret (api next to secret, found in td tag)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? ALso you are missing a ")" in sheto variable before the  .text? Is it a typo?

Comment: Refreshing the page helped in getting the first element through the h3 tag. I'm not getting anything for this code, tho: sheto = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@class='preftable']/tbody/tr/td[@class='prefright']")[1].text
print(sheto)

Comment: Can you please share the html? your screenshot is not showing much info for debuggin

Comment: I'm not getting any errors now. First element is successful. 2nd one doesn't appear. I try to change the [1] to [0] and nothing changes.

Comment: Okay, just a sec

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/wdKgWrB/this.png

Comment: add website!!! or the whole html code of the page

Comment: Terribly sorry, 1st day on stackoverflow. It's https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps - signed in and app created

Comment: @ConfusedCode it's okay, now tell us what the result you wanted to look like, add the expected output

Comment: @chikabala The result would give me the app id (h3 tag) and the secret (the first element in the tr tag). I'm only getting the h3 tag, the 2nd one doesn't produce any kind of output or errors

Comment: @ConfusedCode please add the working output of ur very first code

Comment: @chikabala added to the question now

Comment: @ConfusedCode so ur code isn't showing anything in first place. it thought it gives u a list

Comment: @chikabala it's giving me the first element (h3) but not the 2nd one

Comment: @ConfusedCode it's because u did [0] which means u gonna get only first element, try to remove it, and use find_elements_by_xpath not find_element_by_xpath

Comment: @chikabala Finally working! I found a way around it. Create the app, refresh, click on edit button; all credentials then become available on screen and the text value can be scraped. Thank you for the help, I really do appreciate it.

Comment: @ConfusedCode glad u did find a working solution, and ur welcome always a pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need the text from 1st tr tag.
Try this xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='preftable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='prefright']").text
```

Update:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='preftable']/tbody/tr/th[text()='secret']//following::td[1]").text
```

Comment: Tried that, still not getting any output for the 2nd element. Could you please take a look at https://www.reddit.com/prefs/apps  - signed in and app created, script

Comment: What is this 2nd element?

Comment: "Secret" provided by the app

Comment: Absolute xpath: /html/body/div[3]/div[2]/ul/li/div[4]/div[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td

Comment: Updated my code. Please check and let me know if its working

Comment: Yes, no errors, but I'm still getting just a blank space for that element. It's very weird. I feel like it's detecting the element through using either xpath or tag, but it's like the value is hidden

Comment: xpath i shared is working fine for me. when i run it in the chrome console, it returns whatever text is next to the "secret" element

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_elements_by_` like so:

```
sheto = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//table[@class='preftable']/tbody/tr[1]/td[@class='prefright']")

elementList = sheto.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")

print(elementList.text )
```

`sheto` contains the first element and `elementList` contains the children of it

if sheto contains more than 1 element you can use:

```
for shetos in sheto:
     elementList = shetos.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
     print(elementList.text )
```

Comment: So, I fixed the syntax error, removed the [0] as well as it's not working. Changed h3 to td (tag I'm looking for). Doing the first scenario prompts this error:

    elementList = sheto.find_elements_by_tag_name("td")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_tag_name'

When I go for the 2nd one (for shetos in sheto), I don't get any output for sheto, just a blank space.

Comment: @ConfusedCode forgot to add .text at the end

Comment: Yes, I've added it myself... still the same result

Comment: u have to remove it from sheto because if you do .text in sheto the tags will just go, i did update the code

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' - Very sorry, I'm gonna cry :D

Comment: have you created an app on reddit and got the result yourself? idk, it seems very weird to me

Comment: @ConfusedCode very strange, can u add the output of sheto in your question (with .text)